# create RegEx from variable

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var re = "^abc";
```

How to create a RegEx from this variable to be able to test some strings with it like this:

```
/THE_re_VARIABLE_HERE/i.test( someString );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the [class constructor](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/regexp):

```
var re = "^abc";
new RegExp( re, 'i' ).test( someString );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegExp method:

```
var re = "^abc";
new RegExp(re,'i').test( someString );
```

[See more about RegExp here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)