# Replace words with array map, globaly

Tags: javascript, replace, substring

refering to [Replace words with array map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71547473/replace-words-with-array-map/71547579#71547579)
the answer is good, but I would like to add global replace to it.

```
const arrString = ["beginning=beginner", "leaves=leave", "sound=sounds"];

let string = "its beginner in the sounds leave";

arrString.forEach((mapString) => {
  const stringArr = mapString.split("=");
  string = string.replace(stringArr[1], stringArr[0]);
});

console.log("string", string);
```

I tried

```
string.replace(/stringArr[1]/p, stringArr[0]);
```

Tried it on a string having the same word 3 times.
not working, only the first is replaced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create RegEx from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303426/create-regex-from-variable) (found by [searching for `[javascript] create regex from string`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+create+regex+from+string))

Comment: what is `p` flag supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `String::replaceAll()`, no need in a regular expression here. Also it's confusing that you have your replacements reversed. Semantically I guess would be better `beginner = (means replace beginner with) beginning`.

```js
const arrString = ["beginning=beginner", "leaves=leave", "sound=sounds"];

let string = "its beginner in the sounds leave. beginner again...";

arrString.forEach(mapString => string = string.replaceAll(...mapString.split("=").reverse()));

console.log("string", string);
```

If you want regexp anyway:

```js
const arrString = ["beginning=beginner", "leaves=leave", "sound=sounds"];

let string = "its beginner in the sounds leave. beginner again...";

const replacements = Object.fromEntries(arrString.map(item => item.split('=').reverse()));

string = string.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).join('|'), 'g'), m => replacements[m]);

console.log("string", string);
```

The regexp version seems a bit faster:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

    const arrString = ["beginning=beginner", "leaves=leave", "sound=sounds"];

    let string = "its beginner in the sounds leave. beginner again...".repeat(1000000);

    // @benchmark String::replaceAll()
    {
        let str = string;
        arrString.forEach(mapString => str = str.replaceAll(...mapString.split("=").reverse()));
        str;
    }

    // @benchmark regexp
    {
        const str = string;
        const replacements = Object.fromEntries(arrString.map(item => item.split('=').reverse()));
        str.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).join('|'), 'g'), m => replacements[m]);
    }


</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```